# Print dynamically table records in to the another table

Tags: php, mysql

I retrieve users' name records dynamically and print in a table and now I want to print all those records into another table with different fields of the table, like,

```
table users:
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
```

I get all records dynamically into table with submit button,

```
<?php

$username=$_POST['u_name'];
echo $username;

    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect now");
    mysql_select_db("wp_trainee_management") or die("Database not found");

//$image_caption = $_POST['image_caption'];
//$image_username = $_POST['attendance'];
//$u_name = $_POST['u_name'];
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$insert = "insert into attendance (attendance_date,name,presents)
   values ('$today','".$username."','yes')";
        $insertresults = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

- When I click on to the submit button, I want all these names inserted into the other table.

How can I do it?

Comment: which is second table? elaborate more plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a foreach function to insert each record into another table.

```
foreach($insertdata->result() as $user)
{
   $this->db->insert('attendance',array($user->attendance_date,$user->name,$user->presents));
}
```